# Add tags to a VPC's default Network ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I create a VPC with AWS CloudFormation, it comes with a default network ACL. The VPC gets a few default tags that associates it with the CloudFormation stack: `aws:cloudformation:logical-id`, `aws:cloudformation:stack-id`, `aws:cloudformation:stack-name`, `source`. The default network ACL does not have any tags, nor does it have a name in the AWS management console.

How can I add tags to the default network ACL (from the CloudFormation template)? I'd like to make it clear to any other developers looking at our infrastructure from a crowded console what the network ACL is associated with.

Answer (score 1):

The default Network Access Control List (NACL) is the rule that allows all traffic.
This default NACL is out of scope for Cloud Formation template.

Cloud Formation does not have the provision to modify the default NACL.

Cloud formation template only allows the creation / definition of new Network ACL with tags.

Any NACL created by Cloud Formation will override the default NACL.

**Working example for defining a NACL in Cloud Formation:**

```
"myNetworkAcl" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
   "Properties" : {
      "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "myVPC" },
      "Tags" : [ { "Key" : "foo", "Value" : "bar" } ]
   }
}
```

**More information:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-acl.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't this this is possible to add a name or add tags to the Default NACL with CloudFormation.

If adding tags or a name (i.e. the `Name` tag) is important to you, you could add an explicit [AWS::EC2:NetworkAcl resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-acl.html) to your CloudFormation template with the tags that you desire.